# select LIKE first 3 digits in ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sql-like

How can I adjust the query below to return the records whose area codes are 765?

Note that the `mytable` table has a field Telephone that has numbers in the format `xxxxxxxxxx`, where the first three digits are the area code.  Here is the current SQL, which is not returning any records:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE Telephone LIKE '765%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `left` function.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE left(Telephone,3) = '765'
```

Answer (score 2):

In MS-Access, the wildcard card character is `*`, not `%` as ANSI SQL dictates. Therefore, your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  Telephone LIKE '765*';
```

For additional details, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx).